# R traverse through columns and keep only row that contains '&' or 'and'

Tags: r

I have a dataframe with multiple columns. Column A contains a number where there are duplicates. Column B contains a first name. I want to search through all rows and for equal values of Column A keep only the row that has an '&' symbol or the word 'and' in Column B. If none of the entries has either of those values, then I only want to keep any 1 row it doesn't matter which one. Sample data:

```
Column A           Column B     
12345                John
12345                Mary and Bob
12345                Ben
44444                Jim
44444                Larry & Meg
55555                Tommy
```

Expected output:

```
Column A            Column B
12345               Mary and Bob
44444               Larry & Meg
55555               Tommy
```

Answer (score 3):

You can get the matching rows with `ave` and `grepl`:

```
dat[ave(dat$ColumnB, dat$ColumnA, FUN=function(x) {
  g <- grepl("( & )|( and )", x)
  if (all(!g)) {
    seq_along(x) == 1
  } else {
    g
  }
}) == "TRUE",]
#   ColumnA      ColumnB
# 2   12345 Mary and Bob
# 5   44444  Larry & Meg
# 6   55555        Tommy
```

Data:

```
dat = data.frame(ColumnA=c(12345, 12345, 12345, 44444, 44444, 55555), ColumnB=c("John", "Mary and Bob", "Ben", "Jim", "Larry & Meg", "Tommy"), stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
```

Comment: Nice Solution using less known _ave_ and _[_

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df1)[ , {tmp <- grepl('\\band\\b|&', ColumnB)
               .SD[tmp|all(!tmp)]}, ColumnA]
#   ColumnA      ColumnB
#1:   12345 Mary and Bob
#2:   44444  Larry & Meg
#3:   55555        Tommy
```

Or using `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)
df1 %>% 
   group_by(ColumnA) %>% 
   mutate(tmp= grepl('\\band\\b|&', ColumnB)) %>% 
   filter(tmp|all(!tmp))%>%
   select(-tmp)

#  ColumnA      ColumnB
#1   12345 Mary and Bob
#2   44444  Larry & Meg
#3   55555        Tommy
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(ColumnA = c(12345L, 12345L, 12345L, 44444L, 44444L, 
55555L), ColumnB = c("John", "Mary and Bob", "Ben", "Jim", "Larry & Meg", 
"Tommy")), .Names = c("ColumnA", "ColumnB"), class = "data.frame",
row.names = c(NA, -6L))
```

Comment: @masfenix It is `.Subset of Datatable`

Comment: Good answer, I was working on something very similar until you posted. Maybe it would be better to write the inner command as a separate function for readability

Comment: I don't think the `&` has to be escaped

Comment: @masfenix Sorry I didn't get your comment.   Do you want the `.SD[tmp|all(!tmp)]` to be separated?

Comment: Regex fail for ColumnA == "Mandy"

Comment: @C8H10N4O2  Use word boundary i.e. `\\band\\b`  Thanks for notifying me about a possible case where it fails

Answer (score 0):

You want to split the data set into couples and singles, deduplicate each on the id, and then return all couples and singles for which there is no couple.

```
# Reproducible Example!
df <- data.frame(a=c(rep(12345,3),rep(44444,2),55555),
                 b=c("John","Mary and Bob","Ben","Jim","Larry & Meg","Tommy")
)
couples <- which(grepl("&| and ",df$b,ignore.case=T))

df_couples <- df[couples,][!duplicated(df$a[couples]),]
df_singles <- df[-couples,][!duplicated(df$a[-couples]),]

rbind(df_couples, df_singles[!df_singles$a %in% df_couples$a,])
# 
#       a            b
# 2 12345 Mary and Bob
# 5 44444  Larry & Meg
# 6 55555        Tommy
```